# Pupeteer script freezes

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm writing a script to look domains in a registrar. I managed to get it working, but for some reason the script stops at a random time (after searching 2, 4, 10 domains) and I have no idea why or how I can debug it.
I'm using Puppeteer, but I'm very very new to this, so perhaps I'm making some basic mistakes.

The script so far is as follows:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const DOMS = require('./dominios');

//Traemos los selectores de nic.ar

const SELECTOR_BUSQUEDA = '#edit-txtbuscar';
const SELECTOR_BOTON = '#btn-consultar-block-submit';
const SELECTOR_DNS = '#body > div.dialog-off-canvas-main-canvas > div.main-container.container.js-quickedit-main-content > div > section > div > div > div:nth-child(6) > table.tablaRespon3 > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)';

//Generamos las variables de busqueda

//Funcion principal

async function run() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', 'headless:false']
  });
  let array_doms = [];
  let respuesta = "";
  array_doms = DOMS.Dominios;
  let bodyHandle;
  let resultado;
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  for (let i = 0; i < array_doms.length; i++) {
    await page.goto('https://nic.ar');
    await page.click(SELECTOR_BUSQUEDA);
    await page.keyboard.type(array_doms[i]);
    await page.click(SELECTOR_BOTON);
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    //Trae el selector de la tabla de resultados de la busqueda
    bodyHandle = await page.$('body > div.dialog-off-canvas-main-canvas > div.main-container.container.js-quickedit-main-content > div > section > div > div > div:nth-child(6) > table.tablaRespon3 > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)');
    resultado = await page.evaluate(body => body.innerHTML, bodyHandle);
    await bodyHandle.dispose();
    respuesta = "El dominio " + array_doms[i] + " apunta a " + resultado;
    console.log(respuesta);
  }
};

run();
~
```

I know that the code looks nasty but I'm still learning.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is your script running in non-headless mode and can you see the browser launch and perform the script's actions? Because I noticed you are passing `'headless:false'` to the args key, but I think the way to do that is by passing it in as a separate key/value pair. i.e. `puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],headless: false
  });`

Comment: No, I can't see the browser. And I don't know the right way to pass arguments to puppeteer.launch(), I just copied from some tutorial.

Comment: Ok, try the one I posted in my comment. That is the config I am using and it does work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There may be a race condition in these two lines:

```js
await page.click(SELECTOR_BOTON);
await page.waitForNavigation();
```

Sometimes navigation happens before page click resolved, sometimes after this. To avoid this effect, try to replace these lines with these ones:

```js
await Promise.all([
  page.click(SELECTOR_BOTON),
  page.waitForNavigation(),
]);
```